# PHP - Display SQL results in multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, html-table, odbc

I have a database table with student room assignments.  Each student has a specific hall, floor, and apartment.  I need to display each student in a specific table so the results look like a floor layout.  Below is an example.  The student ID needs to be in the correct Apartment slot.  There could be several ID's per apartment.  Right now it just lists them down the page.

Apartment 102 Apartment 101

Apartment 104 Apartment 103

Apartment 106 Apartment 105

```
$query = "select res.ID_NUM as ID, res.APARTMENT
From Residents res
Where res.sess_cde = '$pulledsession'
and res.ROOM_ASSIGN_STS = 'A'
and res.BLDG_CDE = '$pulledhall'
and res.FLOOR = '$pulledfloor'";


$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);


echo "<table style='padding:25;'>
<tr>
<th>Apartment</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";
while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){ 
$ID = odbc_result($result,ID);
$APARTMENT = odbc_result($result,APARTMENT);

if ($APARTMENT == $pulledfloor.'01')
{  
echo "<tr   >";
echo "<td>" . $pulledfloor.'01' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ID . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($APARTMENT == $pulledfloor.'02')
{  
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pulledfloor.'02' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ID . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($APARTMENT == $pulledfloor.'03')  
{ 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pulledfloor.'03' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ID . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($APARTMENT == $pulledfloor.'04')
{  
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pulledfloor.'04' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ID . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($APARTMENT == $pulledfloor.'05')
{  
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pulledfloor.'05' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ID . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
else if ($APARTMENT == $pulledfloor.'06')
{  
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $pulledfloor.'06' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $ID . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: need your schema to go forward

Comment: So, where do you have the link from student and apartment?

Comment: I "dumb-ed" down the code to make it easy, but each student record has all the info needed (hall, floor, apartment, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to retrieve the room number as well. After that, one way to do it would be to load the results into an associated array:

```
$rooms[$row['roomNumber']] = $resName; // Example
```

Once you have the array built, then you can echo it back out into a table, either manually (build the full table and echo each one with

```
echo "<tr><td>".$rooms['102']."</td><td>".$rooms['101']."</td></tr>";
```

or similar, or do it dynamically by incrementing two room numbers in a loop.

If you have multiple students in a room, then tack on more depth to the array:

```
$rooms[$row['roomNumber']][] = $resName;
```

Then use a loop in each cell to echo it back out.